# How to store the prolog list returned by the query in the python?

Tags: python, prolog

I have written a code in python that tries to run prolog queries through pyswip. There is one problem: the output shows the type and address instead of the actual values of the atoms. Can anybody tell me why it is happening so and is there any other function to take prolog list and store in a python list?

```
from pyswip import Prolog
p = Prolog()
p.retractall('tran(_,_)')
p.retractall('listtran(_,_)')
p.assertz('tran(eins,one)')
p.assertz('tran(zwei,two)')
p.assertz('tran(drei,three)')
p.assertz('tran(vier,four)')
p.assertz('tran(fuenf,five)')
p.assertz('tran(sechs,six)')
p.assertz('tran(sieben,seven)')
p.assertz('tran(acht,eight)')
p.assertz('tran(neun,nine)')    
p.assertz('listtran([],[])')
p.assertz('listtran([X|Tx],[Y|Ty]) :- tran(X,Y) , listtran(Tx,Ty)')

Val = list(p.query('listtran([eins,zwei,drei,vier],Z)'))
print(Val)
```

Output:-

```
[{'Z': [Atom('468997'), Atom('469381'), Atom('469765'), Atom('470149')]}]
```

Well, I find this [link](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/issues/16) where this issue was raised, but I couldn't get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The alternate solution which worked for me, but still unable to read the prolog list

```
from pyswip import Prolog
p = Prolog()
p.retractall('tran(_,_)')
p.retractall('listtran(_,_)')
p.assertz("tran(eins,one)")
p.assertz('tran(zwei,two)')
p.assertz('tran(drei,three)')
p.assertz('tran(vier,four)')
p.assertz('tran(fuenf,five)')
p.assertz('tran(sechs,six)')
p.assertz('tran(sieben,seven)')
p.assertz('tran(acht,eight)')
p.assertz('tran(neun,nine)')    
p.assertz('listtran([],[])')
p.assertz('listtran([X|Tx],[Y|Ty]) :- tran(X,Y) , listtran(Tx,Ty)')

for soln in p.query('listtran([eins,zwei,drei],[X,Y,Z])'):
    print(soln)
```

Output:-

```
{'X': 'one', 'Y': 'two', 'Z': 'three'}
```